# comparing multidimensional arrays and getting the values of matched keys

Tags: php

I have two multidimensional arrays to compare and I have to get the key and values of only matched keys.

My first array:

```
stdClass Object
(
[CPU load] => Array
(
[0] => load1
[1] => load5
[2] => load15
)

[CPU utilization] => Array
(
[0] => user
[1] => wait
)

[Disk IO SUMMARY] => Array
(
[0] => read
[1] => write
)

[Interface 2] => Array
(
[0] => in
[1] => inucast
[2] => innucast
[3] => indisc
[4] => inerr
[5] => out        
[6] => outucast        

)


)
```

My second array:

```
array(
[1] => Array
(
[_id] => MongoId Object
(
[$id] => 543ad15bc863c7b96b3b3d81
)

[hosts_group_name] => my all groups
[hosts_and_services] => Array
(

[Redmine] => Array
(
[0] => Disk IO SUMMARY
[1] => Interface 2
)

)

[customerIdentifier] => devmaas
)

)

)
```

What I want is:

```
$graph=array('Disk IO SUMMARY'=>array('load1','load5','load15'),
'Interface 2'=>array('user','wait'));
```

What I tried is:

```
$newarray1=array(); 
$newarray2=array(); 
foreach ($this->graphMap as $key => $val) {
    $newarray1[]=$key;
}
foreach ($select_host_group_details as $group_details){
    foreach($group_details['hosts_and_services'] as $key=>$val){
        foreach($val as $k=>$v){
            $newarray2[]=$v;
        } 
    }
}
if($newarray1==$newarray2)
{
}
```

Help me on this I am not getting how to compare it and combine these arrays.